# Equation and image in a row

Tags: graphics, equations, positioning, two-column

I have example (defined as `\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]`) and inside
I have four-level equation of same size as an image ABC.png that I want to put on the right from the equation. But it is always below. I want them to be in a row in a twocolumn document prepared for Elsevier.

```
\begin{example}
  \begin{equation*}
    \begin{align*}
      |\, A \cap B \cap C \,| = 1 & \\
      |\, A \cap B \, \setminus C \,| > 0 & \\
      |\, A \cap C \, \setminus B \,| > 0 & \\
      |\, B \cap C \, \setminus A \,| > 0 &.
    \end{align*}
  \end{equation*}
  \hfill
  \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{./images/ABC}
\end{example}
```

Unreal? :)

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 2):

```
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{example}
  \begin{equation*}
    \begin{align*}
      |\, A \cap B \cap C \,| = 1 & \\
      |\, A \cap B \, \setminus C \,| > 0 & \\
      |\, A \cap C \, \setminus B \,| > 0 & \\
      |\, B \cap C \, \setminus A \,| > 0 &.
    \end{align*}
  \end{equation*}
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill
  \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{./images/ABC}
\end{example}
```